# ignoring root role in a proxy enpoint

Tags: nginx

My subdomain `sbd.example.org` is a webservice that need to return an HTML static page when request is a GET to the root (`/`),
and is a proxy rewrite for any other case (eg. `/t`). So I need

- GET `http://sbd.example.org` to usual *root* index and *try_files*
- GET `http://sbd.example.org/t` rewrite to a proxy

but my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/sbd` is not working as expected. This is the problematic source:

```
server {

       server_name sbd.example.org;

       root /var/www/sbd/html;

       index index.html index.htm;

       location / {
               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
       }

       location ~ ^/[a-z].+$ {
          rewrite ^/(.*)$ /$1 break;
          proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:3000;
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          default_type  application/json;
          proxy_hide_header Content-Location;
          proxy_set_header  Connection "";
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
       }

}
```

**Error**: the GET `http://sbd.example.org/` is not an HTML page but an JSON with error message generated  by proxy as a request for `http://sbd.example.org/index.htm`.

**How to correct my Nginx script?**

PS: all `http://sbd.example.org/etc` is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than identify what needs to be sent to the proxy, it may be easier to identify what files are static.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
}
location @proxy {
    proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for more.